# Result of the method GET brings all relations and subrelations

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have an application in which I have a list screen

[image]

I'm doing a method in my API Spring boot

class controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/distritos", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Distritos>> buscarTodosDistritos() {
        Collection<Distritos> distritosBuscados = distritosService.buscarTodos();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(distritosBuscados, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

class service

```
public Collection<Distritos> buscarTodos(){
                return distritosRepository.findAll();
            }
```

class repository

```
@Repository
public interface DistritosRepository extends JpaRepository<Distritos, Integer> {

}
```

class Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "distritos", schema="glb")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Distritos.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Distritos d"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Distritos.findByIdDistrito", query = "SELECT d FROM Distritos d WHERE d.idDistrito = :idDistrito"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Distritos.findByNome", query = "SELECT d FROM Distritos d WHERE d.nome = :nome"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Distritos.findByCodigoDne", query = "SELECT d FROM Distritos d WHERE d.codigoDne = :codigoDne"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Distritos.findByFlagAtivo", query = "SELECT d FROM Distritos d WHERE d.flagAtivo = :flagAtivo")})



@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "idDistrito", scope= Distritos.class)        
public class Distritos implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_distrito")
    private int idDistrito;


    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 70)
    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;


    @Size(max = 8)
    @Column(name = "codigo_dne")
    private String codigoDne;


    @Column(name = "flag_ativo")
    private Integer flagAtivo;


    @JoinColumn(name="idEntidade")
    @ManyToOne
    private Entidades entidade;


    @JoinColumn(name="idMunicipio")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Municipios municipio;


    @JoinColumn(name="idUf")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Ufs uf;

    public Distritos() {
    }

   gets and sets....
   }
```

in my js of front end i have this

```
carregarDados = function() {

        token = localStorage.getItem("userToken");

        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/user/distritos'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.distritos = response.data;

        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });
    };
```

the problem is that the return of the GET method brings all the relationships, causing an excessive delay, and their subrelations, being that I only need the name of the Estado, name of the Municipio and name of the Eentidade.

The strange thing is that the result of the second listing of the array brings exactly the information I need without the subrelations.

Look at the picture.

[image]

Comment: try with lazy relationships

Comment: How to do this ?

Comment: @EduardoKrakhecke  `@ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`

Comment: i try that and i got this erro `Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed` and  `No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->digifred.global.model.Distritos["entidade"]->digifred.global.model.Entidades_$$_jvstfb1_10["municipio"]->digifred.global.model.Municipios_$$_jvstfb1_4["uf"]->digifred.global.model.Ufs_$$_jvstfb1_15["handler"])`

Answer (score 0):

The error was in my related classes, for example in municipio, entidade and uf I had an `@OneToMany` mapping and within those classes more `@OneToMany` mappings that were unnecessary. So when I was doing a `GET` in distritos I had a response with all the mappings, including bidirectional ones that were unnecessary, causing a slowness.